# Router navigate not hitting component method

Tags: angular

I have the following routing:

```
path: 'task',
component: TaskComponent,
children: [
    {
        path: ':category/:id',
        component: TaskEditComponent
    }
]
```

on my `TaskComponent`, I have a `list` of div that are clickable and will redirect to the path above

```
<div *ngFor="let url of urlList; let i = index" (click)="goToLink(url)">
```

this `urlList` contains: `/task/personal/10` where `personal` is the category and `10` is the id.

Now on my `TaskComponent`, I have the `goToLink` method:

```
goToLink(url: string) {
    this._router.navigate([url]);
}
```

Now this is working, I can see that my url is changing. But i am not hitting the constructor or the OnInit method of the component specified on my routing which is `TaskEditComponent`. Please note that on first load, I am able to hit the constructor, but when I click other url on my div, i am not hitting it.

```
export class TaskEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('should hit this')
    }
}
```

I am reading life cycle hooks but I need help on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: this is most likely due to router reusing the component, try adding the following to the constructor of the TaskEditComponent: `constructor(r: ActivatedRoute) { r.url.subscribe((s:UrlSegment[]) => { console.log("url", s); }); }`, do you get logging when changing states?

Comment: yes, it is logging now. thanks for the help!

Comment: sure, can I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes of course you can.

Comment: done, you can accept it now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the route parameters change, `Router` reuses the component instance and doesn't instantiate it, so constructor and `onInit` don't get called. So if you've been here:

```
/task/personal/10
```

and now navigate to

```
/task/personal/11
```

only the parameter changed, so the component will be reused. An easy way to verify it is to put the following in the constructor:

```
constructor(r: ActivatedRoute) { 
    r.url.subscribe((s:UrlSegment[]) => { console.log("url", s); }); 
}
```

It should log every time you switch the route.